# Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project projectID. Add instance <project> to the constraint to use external IP with it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a Jupyter Notebook but I keep getting an error saying

```
Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project <projectID>. Add instance <project> to the constraint to use external IP with it.
```

I created the VPC network and the notebook tries to create itself but I cannot get past that error.

Answer (score 8):

The issue you are facing is with the organization policy that was blocking you from creating a JUPYTER notebook.

This error is related to violating [constraint](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/overview#constraints) rules in your project. Looks like your organization has a policy to not allow external IP. Your issue is caused by your [organization policy constraint](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints) applied to this project. By default, all VM instances are allowed to use external IP addresses. The allowed/denied list of VM instances must be identified by the VM instance name, in the form: projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/ZONE/instances/INSTANCE. You will need to reach your organization admins to provide you proper permissions.

**The error is occurring for two reasons:**

1. GCP,  by default, will try to assign external IP addresses to instances
2. There is an organizational policy that prevents the creation of VMs with external IP addresses.
   So because GCP is trying to create an external IP but the org policy prevents this, you are seeing an error that implies that you are trying to create a Jupyter Notebook using the VM with an external IP.

As a workaround, you can try adding the instance to the constraint of a project . Refer to the [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#setorgpolicy) to see how to add an instance to the constraints of a project.

**NOTE :** To set a constraint on either the project or the organization level, you must have been granted the **orgpolicy.policyAdmin** role on the organization.

You can also try using the --no-address flag explicitly when creating a VM, which tells GCP to not add an external IP address.

Refer [Define Allowed External IPs for VM Instances](https://www.trendmicro.com/cloudoneconformity/knowledge-base/gcp/ResourceManager/allowed-external-ips.html) for information.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using a private IP if you don't have any specific need for a notebook VM instances with public IP.

If you are using IAAC like terraform to create notebook instances you can use [no pulic ip](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/notebooks_instance#no_public_ip) option.

Or specify it from the console like this during network selection.[image]