# Creating a Vertex AI Workbench with a Non Organization Account and problems with constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workbench, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to create a Vertex AI Workbench on GCP, but every time I try I get the following error:

*<Workbench Name> Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project <Project ID>. Add instance <Workbench ID> to the constraint to use external IP with it.*

I went to the Organization Policies page to edit the constraint: *constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess* and saw that is denied for all (which is odd because in the [constraints documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints) it says that is should be enabled for all by default). Now, the problem is that when I go to edit the constraint, it says that it requires this set of permissions:

- *orgpolicy.policies.create*
- *orgpolicy.policies.delete*
- *orgpolicy.policies.update*
- *orgpolicy.policy.get*

which are all part of the role: *roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin* that can only be granted at an organization level, and well, I have a Non Organization Account.

Am I missing something?

Thank for your time!

Comment: You will need a Google Cloud Organization to use Organization Policies. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization

Comment: You need to have an organization ID to set up [policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization). Moreover [Vertex AI uses Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control) to manage access to resources and please check this [setup](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/featurestore/setup?hl=in) guide. If this solves your query will post this an answer.

Comment: Thanks @AbhijithChitrapu. I already have all the aiplatform.* permissions (I have an "Owner" role), but I still get the same error. So without an Organization ID you can't deploy a Vertex AI Workbench?

Comment: @SantiagoCerónUribe, This [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70180992) might be useful. Check and confirm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project projectID. Add instance <project> to the constraint to use external IP with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70180992/constraint-constraints-compute-vmexternalipaccess-violated-for-project-projectid)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the recommended solution is to create an Organization.

In the linked answer this possible workaround is also mentioned:

> You can also try using the --no-address flag explicitly when creating a VM, which tells GCP to not add an external IP address.