# Create CloudSQL instance without public IP

Tags: go, google-cloud-sql

I have a program that creates a CloudSQL instance into our project.
My organization has recently introduced a Policy that prevents the creation of CloudSQL instances with a Public IP (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/org-policy/org-policy#connection_organization_policies) `Restrict public IP access on Cloud SQL instances`

My code however, should not be adding a public IP on the instance anyway, since the setting `Ipv4Enabled` is false.

Here is how I create the instance:

```
    scannerInstance := &sqladmin.DatabaseInstance{
        DatabaseVersion: targetInstance.DatabaseVersion,
        Settings: &sqladmin.Settings{
            IpConfiguration: &sqladmin.IpConfiguration{
                RequireSsl:     true,
                Ipv4Enabled:    false,
                PrivateNetwork: cloudSqlRequest.VpcNetwork,
            },
            Kind: "sql#settings",
            AvailabilityType:           "ZONAL",
            DatabaseFlags:              targetInstance.Settings.DatabaseFlags,
            BackupConfiguration:        &sqladmin.BackupConfiguration{Enabled: false},
            DatabaseReplicationEnabled: false,
            DataDiskSizeGb:             targetInstance.Settings.DataDiskSizeGb,
            Tier:                       targetInstance.Settings.Tier,
            TimeZone:                   targetInstance.Settings.TimeZone,
        },
        Name:         InstanceName,
        InstanceType: "CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE",
        Project:      cloudSqlRequest.ProjectId,
        Region:       targetInstance.Region,
        RootPassword: rootPassword,
    }

    _, err = scannerClient.SqlService.Instances.Insert(cloudSqlRequest.ScannerProjectId, scannerInstance).Context(ctx).Do()
```

However, when this code runs, I get this error:

```
googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: Organization Policy check failure: the external IP of this instance violates the constraints/sql.restrictPublicIp enforced at the XXX project
```

From the documentation `Ipv4Enabled` is what determines whether a public IP is attached to the instance or not.
How can I create this instance without triggering this policy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project projectID. Add instance <project> to the constraint to use external IP with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70180992/constraint-constraints-compute-vmexternalipaccess-violated-for-project-projectid)

Comment: Not really. The constraint in this answer is different, also it pertains to VMs not to CloudSQL instances, there is no `--no-address` flag for CloudSQL instance creation. Also changing the constraint policy isn't an option for me as this is company policy.

Comment: @RobertG after some investigation it looks like an issue with the Go SDK client. I've looked at the request received by GCP in the logs and `ipv4Enabled` is missing from the request, like it's dropped from the body.